Privacy-impacting third-party SDK in a Flutter app
I received the following email from Apple:

ITMS-91061: Missing privacy manifest - Your app includes > “Frameworks/share_plus.framework/share_plus”, which includes share_plus, an SDK that > was identified in the documentation as a privacy-impacting third-party SDK. Starting > February 12, 2025, if a new app includes a privacy-impacting SDK, or an app update > adds a new privacy-impacting SDK, the SDK must include a privacy manifest file. > Please contact the provider of the SDK that includes this file to get an updated SDK > version with a privacy manifest. For more details about this policy, including a list > of SDKs that are required to include signatures and manifests

I use Share Plus version 7.2.2 which does not have privacy manifest file yet but I am currently unable to upgrade it to a newer version since it would then bring a restriction that I should start using Dart version 3 where I am not there yet considering my other dependencies!
So I am wondering what options I have... Will Apple accept my app's new submission if I add this manifest file to my project itself rather than it is being presented in the third-party SDK? Or what else can I do, please?
